# accessing a collection as if it was a DB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was wondering if it is possible to work with mongoose, using a collection as a database.

The scenario is, i am using a hosting where i can only have a database, but i want to create various sites, that use different databases. so i would have, locally, this:

```
var dbUrl = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1/database';
mongoose.connect(dbUrl);
```

and my database, would have a collection for each "db" i wanted to use, for instance:

```
db.site1;
db.site2;
db.site3;
```

Then, i would setup mongoose, to treat `db.site1` as my main database for this particular site.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: Nope.  Databases and collections are completely differently things.

Comment: Databases and collections cannot be used interchangeably in any way.  Are you sure that the hosting is only letting you have a single database?  It's possible that they are only letting you have a single MongoDB server, which can actually hold multiple databases.

Comment: Oh, that is probably the case. Put it as an answer and i will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases and collections cannot be used interchangeably in any way. Are you sure that the hosting is only letting you have a single database? It's possible that they are only letting you have a single MongoDB server, which can actually hold multiple databases.